# Precise positioning of markers for lat/lon

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, marker

I'm trying to centre a 40x40 marker at a lat/lon position in an itemizedOverlay for a mapview.

I set the marker bounds with

```
    markerDefault.setBounds( -markerDefault.getIntrinsicWidth()/2
            ,-markerDefault.getIntrinsicHeight()/2
            , markerDefault.getIntrinsicWidth()/2
            , markerDefault.getIntrinsicHeight()/2);
```

When I check the lat/lon by tapping the centre of the marker image, the lat seems to be wrong by about the height of the image.

Is there a way to ensure the image is centred at the required lat/lon?

Is it possible the default mouse cursor - an arrow - isn't doing its usual behaviour of using its pointy end to interact with the emulator?

Thanks,

Geoff

Comment: I'm using the emulator, so the 'tap' is actually a mouse click. I use the onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) method to detect the point and get the lat-lon from p.

Answer (score 0):

The answer -

I'm using an ItemisedOverlay. When an OverlayItem is added, you can specify whether the marker is positioned with its centre at the position, or its lower edge at the position. See [ItemizedOverlay.](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html#boundCenter%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

I had copy-and-pasted some nice code for an ItemizedOverlay I found( on stackoverflow of course), which included

```
super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
```

This caused the apparent anomaly I found. Its good if you're using a pin-type marker tho. I changed it to

```
super(boundCenter(defaultMarker));
```

and it works as expected.